# How can i create an array of instances in c++?

Tags: c++

Consider this device class

```
class Device
{
private:
    char * uid = {0};
    char * name = {0};
    
public:
    Device()
    {
        this->uid = {0};
        this->name = {0};
    }

    Device(char * uid, char * name, SensorType sensorType)
    {
        this->uid = uid;
        this->name = name;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        Serial.print(this->uid);
        Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print(this->name);
        Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print(this->sensorType);
        Serial.println();
    }
};
```

and an array of such devices

```
Device Devices[32];
```

Upon on websocket messages, i receive the json data and (i suppose) i create an instance of the class like so

```
    int temp = 0;

    void FooNewData(){
        char *uid = (char *)json["uid"].as<char *>();
        char *name = (char *)json["name"].as<char *>();
        SensorType sensorType = json["sensorType"].as<SensorType>();
            
        Devices[temp] = Device(uid, name, sensorType);
            
        temp++; // <-- this variable just increases the index
    }
```

So when i send this data on first time

```
{
  "uid" : "1",
  "name" : "test 1",
  "sensorType": 1
}
```

`Devices[0]` has the correct data. But if i then send new data

```
{
  "uid" : "2",
  "name" : "test 2",
  "sensorType": 1
}
```

Both `Devices[0]` and `Devices[1]` have the same last sent data. (in this example uid = 2 and name =2). What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Device is only storing char* and not std::string. Obvious question for me is are they "reused" by json ?

Comment: @John3136 I would be searching for ages. Thanks!

Comment: Use `std::string`, not `char *`.  When using C++, the first option is to use `std::string`.